# How to update the weights in WeightedIndex?

Tags: rust

I want to update the weights for the key after its drawn, how can I do that.

```
use rand::distributions::WeightedIndex;
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let items = [('a', 0), ('b', 3), ('c', 7)];
    let dist2 = WeightedIndex::new(items.iter().map(|item| item.1)).unwrap();
 
    for _ in 0..10 {
        // 0% chance to print 'a', 30% chance to print 'b', 70% chance to print 'c'
        println!("{}", items[dist2.sample(&mut rng)].0);

        // dist2.update_weights(new_weights: &[(usize, &X)])
    }
}
```

That is when "b" is drawn, I want to set the weight for b to zero, so that its no longer drawn, or set it to some other weight.

https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/distributions/weighted/struct.WeightedIndex.html

Comment: You just need to call `update_weights` and provide the index of `('b', 3)` in `items`. You might want to track that separately if the collection is large.

Comment: Ya, written the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use rand::distributions::WeightedIndex;
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let items = [('a', 8), ('b', 5), ('c', 1)];
    let mut dist2 = WeightedIndex::new(items.iter().map(|item| item.1)).unwrap();
    for _ in 0..3 {
        let index = dist2.sample(&mut rng);
        println!("{}", index);
        println!("{:?}", items[index].0);

        dist2.update_weights(&[(index, &0)]).unwrap();
    }
}
```

You just need to call the `update_weights` function on the same distribution - it will mutate the existing distribution, so there is no need to reassign. Note that the return value of `update_weights` is just a `Result<(), WeightedError>`. An `Ok(())` indicates that the mutation of the distribution was succesful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
use rand::distributions::WeightedIndex;
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let items = [('a', 8), ('b', 5), ('c', 1)];
    let mut dist2 = WeightedIndex::new(items.iter().map(|item| item.1)).unwrap();
    for _ in 0..3 {
        // 0% chance to print 'a', 30% chance to print 'b', 70% chance to print 'c'
        let index = dist2.sample(&mut rng);
        println!("{}", index);
        println!("{:?}", items[index].0);

        let _d = dist2.update_weights(&[(index, &0)]);
    }
}
```